# Adding new static page in CartoView / GeoNode?

Tags: django, geonode

I have installed the CartoView with the Windows stable build installer.

Then, I try to add a static page to the newly installed CartoView / GeoNode by modifying the `urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
# Static pages
url(r'^test/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='test.html'), name='test')
]
```

The test page entry doesn't work and localhost/test/ throws an error with no test page entry shown in the error log.

Has anyone successfully added a static page in GeoNode / CartoView?

Is there a compile action that I have been missing in forcing the `urls.pyc` update?

Comment: Did you restart apache installed by cartoview installer??

Comment: yes. nothing have been changed.